# vb.net display some value based on a value returned by a datasources

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, data-binding, webforms, datasource

I'm rather new to .net, so this may be a simple question.

I have a webforms webapp with a datasource. It returns with a bunch of values, one of them is a datatime typed value which is nullable. I would like to display an image based on this value. There would be 3 cases. 1, its null, 2, it isn't older than 14 day and 3, the rest.

I would like to solve this in the .vb file (i.e.: i dont want to write a long IIf(.... statement in the .aspx file) but can't find where should I do some processing on the db result before it get's displayed.

Comment: What have you tried?  This seems like a fairly short IF/ElseIF or Case statement.  You could also return another field from your data source which then determines what image to show.

Comment: to return with some new field is something i don't really want. If that field is not the url of the image then I still have to do the processing the same way I have to do now, and to return the url is something i definitely don't want. I tried to find how .net world solves such problems with no luck so far. Came from the java world, there would take no time to solve this problem.

Comment: So what i'm really looking for is to find a place ??event, overridden method?? where i can declare a variable (or "virtual" column) for each row returned by the db so that I can write in the .aspx code `<%# Eval("myNewColumnWithTheURL") %>`

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution, it may help to anyone in the same situation:

It's the ItemDataBound event which needs to implement. It gets every single row after it got retrieve from the db.